# Doing something just because you have to do it. Doing something half-heartedly

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am looking for verbs, adverbs, and/or adjectives that express actions done just for the sake of having to do them. Wanting to do something the easiest way possible just to get over with it, and therefore being careless of cursory.

For example:

I  _____ through my homework because I was not in the mood for doing it. I did it ____.

Comment: The previous answer does not address the verb request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I **muddled through** my homework because I was not in the mood for
> doing it. I did it **on autopilot**.

If an adverb is required:

> I **muddled through** my homework because I was not in the mood for
> doing it. I did it **perfunctorily**.

**muddled through** (v.)

> To achieve a degree of success without much planning or effort
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muddle%20through)

**autopilot** (n.)

> Doing something without thinking about it or without making an effort
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/on-autopilot)

> *Figurative*. Automatic or mechanical action, behaviour, or routine. Chiefly in ***on autopilot***: (acting or happening) according to routine or
> habit, without concentration or conscious thought. OED

**perfunctorily** (adv.)

> In a perfunctory manner; as a matter of mere duty, form, or routine;
> with a minimum of effort, care, or interest OED

---

> No wonder our kids are worn out by evening, just in time to start
> their homework. They **muddle through** it, often skipping the items
> necessitating creative thought, and rarely have the energy or
> motivation to call a friend for help on a particularly tricky problem.
> [Ruth Peters; *Overcoming Underachieving*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Overcoming_Underachieving/IltF-6A5DgEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=motivated%20muddled%20through%20homework&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover)

> Some young people soon lose interest; some **muddle through
> half-heartedly**, doing just enough to get by... [A. F. Villaneuva;
> *Improved Methods in the Teaching of the National Language*, p.6](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22muddle%20through%22%20assignments%20half-heartedly&biw=1146&bih=438&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvKmbveX0yYCz7kY8jzIemotOovO-w%3A1634119503400&ei=T69mYfnlF_CoytMP1KWPkAs&oq=%22muddle%20through%22%20assignments%20half-heartedly&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23112.24996.0.25219.12.12.0.0.0.0.251.1132.1j6j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.1.136...33i10k1.0.MCv13OOI5IA)

> The week raced by in a flurry of projects, reports, and assignments. I
> was **on autopilot**. The only thing that pulled me out of my stupor
> was getting a D on an Astronomy pop quiz. A *D*. In *Astronomy*, of
> all things. [Ronni Davis; *When the Stars Lead to You*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/When_the_Stars_Lead_to_You/Z4OLDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=homework%20on%20autopilot&pg=PT223&printsec=frontcover)

> Grading repetitive homework was a nightmare for me. If I got bored
> grading it, I knew the students were **on autopilot** (read: **not
> thinking**) while doing it. [N. Cambron-McCabe et al.; *Schools That
> Learn*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Schools_That_Learn/xdCMDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=homework%20on%20autopilot&pg=PA219&printsec=frontcover)

> Teachers were also influenced by the serious possibility that a number
> of students either would not do their homework or would do it
> **perfunctorily**. [J. Elliott et al.; *Motivation, Engagement and Educational Performance, p.162*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Motivation_Engagement_and_Educational_Pe/V3qJDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=homework%20perfunctorily&pg=PA162&printsec=frontcover)

> Pupils will get the impression that the teacher does not value
> homework as a learning tool, and will attempt to complete it as
> quickly and **perfunctorily** as possible. [D. Muijs and D. Reynolds;
> *Effective Teaching*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Effective_Teaching/apc3DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=homework%20perfunctorily&pg=PA143&printsec=frontcover)